# ListActivity Performance Issues

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks, listactivity, hprof

I have serious problems with my `ListActivity`. When I open it and start scrolling, the app freezes for some seconds and after that it can be scrolled smoothly. I don't get an "application not responding" error. I made a `*.hprof` heap dump and put it into MAT. Here you can see my leaks:

[image: Memory Analysis with MAT]

[image: Memory Leak Suspects]

Seems like something is fishy. Maybe I'm not using the cursor in the right way.
Here you can take a look at my code:

```java
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    // Resources
    static String like;

    // Cursor
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private Cursor cursor;
    String[] showColumns;
    int[] showViews;

    // Database
    private DBAccess dbAccess;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

        ListViewActivity.like = "";
        Intent intent = getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
        ListViewActivity.like = intent.getStringExtra("like");

        new DatabaseTask().execute(null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {     
        Cursor item = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, ListClickActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", item.getString(0));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class DatabaseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.v("doInBackground", "started!");

            dbAccess = new DBAccess(ListViewActivity.this, 1, "FishingMatey.db");

            dbAccess.initDownloadedDatabase();

            cursor = dbAccess
                    .createBewirtschafterListViewCursor(ListViewActivity.like);

            showColumns = new String[] { "gewName", "reviergrenzen" };
            showViews = new int[] { R.id.datensatz_gewName,
                    R.id.datensatz_reviergrenzen };

            Log.v("doInBackground", "finished!");

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ListViewActivity.this,
                    R.layout.datensatz, cursor, showColumns, showViews);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            dbAccess.closeDatabase();

            Log.v("onPostExecute", "finished!");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT1:**
The issue doesn't come from the database because I have the same leak with the following code:

```java
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
// Activity
public static Activity forFinish;

// Resources
static String like;

// Cursor
private SimpleAdapter adapter;
String[] showColumns;
int[] showViews;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

    forFinish = this;
    
    ListViewActivity.like = "";
    Intent intent = getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
    ListViewActivity.like = intent.getStringExtra("like");

    // create the grid item mapping

    showColumns = new String[] { "gewName", "reviergrenzen" };
    showViews = new int[] { R.id.datensatz_gewName,
            R.id.datensatz_reviergrenzen };

    // prepare the list of all records
    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("gewName", "See" + i);
        map.put("reviergrenzen", "Revier" + i);
        fillMaps.add(map);

    }
    // fill in the grid_item layout

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps,
            R.layout.datensatz, showColumns, showViews);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Would be awesome if someone can find the memory leak.
Greetings Mike!

Comment: Do you get the same lag if you populate it with dummy information (and images, if necessary), instead of from the DB? Does it lag *after* it's populated, or before?

Comment: I'll try it, but how can I figure it out, if it lags before it's populated or afterwards?

Comment: If, when it lags, there is data in the list. (I assume so since the issue is with scrolling; if there was no data, you couldn't scroll.)

Comment: I have the same issue with dummy information. Please look at the edit.

Comment: Seeing as the `Bitmap` objects are the culprit, can you post the relevant code where you apply/gather Bitmaps for your `ListView`?

Comment: Seems like the leak comes from the Activity which runs behind. It's a MapFragment with Google Map API V2. [Google](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766) confirmed that the current API has serious issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using images in your list items then move the image loading to a background task. You could have a look at [smoothie](https://github.com/lucasr/smoothie), an asynchronous loading list that can be used with [Android-BitmapCache](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache) for better performance.